# React popup window.open null opener when triggered from useEffects first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to trigger a popup on initial page load (based on certain conditions). The purpose being for oauth authentication. I have everything working through a button click, but for some reason when trying to open the popup using a `useEffect`, I run into the issue where the `window.opener` is null and therefore cannot callback.

I have made a minimal demo here outlining the issue. Immediately upon loading, it should attempt to open a popup automatically. If you allow it, and then run `window.opener` in the console of the popup, you'll see that it is null

[image]

However, pressing on either button (direct or through the *same* use `useEffect` via a state dependency) the window will open again and the `opener` will no longer be null.

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-shannon-t0xjo

Comment: works for me, nothing in console either

Comment: you have to call `window.opener` yourself in the console of the popup (it won't happen on its own). What are you saying works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you browser is blocking popups as it is not an user initialised event?